# Make /etc/resolv.conf changes permanent in WSL 2

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, resolv.conf

On WSL 2, when I try to connect to a website, I get an issue:

```
$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Now, to fix this, I had to add `/etc/wsl.conf` with this content:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = true
```

And I need to change my `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

This works fine.

However when I restart my system, when I shutdown wsl or do anything similar, `/etc/resolv.conf` is overwritten with the previous value.

Of course, if I change `/etc/wsl.conf` to the following and restart again:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

The fix mentioned above is gone again.

So how do I make my changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` permanent on WSL 2?

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is typically a symlink, and gets overwritten by NetPlan / SystemD.  When it 'overwrites' the data what do you see in `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @ThomasWard this is the result of that command: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 25 17:43 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. I thought that `..` was relative to my own directory, so I tried in other directories and it's still `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. And I see that that file currently has `8.8.8.8` as value anyways.

Comment: OK that's normal. When you are altering things, make sure you look at `/etc/resolvconf` - somewhere in there is a 'head' file you can configure to have your primary DNS servers yourself ahead of anything set by the system - this is useful because that's how resolvconf works with dynamic network connections (Network Manager) in a base install of Ubuntu. Just for the future so they stay. Edit the head file for resolvconf, those changes are persistent. There may be OTHER items that get created underneath that but you'ill set primary DNS with that way. If that works I'll convert this to an answer

Comment: @ThomasWard `sudo find /run -type f`, returns only `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and `/run/sudo/ts/myusername`. There is nothing else in there.

Comment: I didn't say it's in `/run` - note the directory i said in my comment is **`/etc/resolvconf`**, and is *not* in `/run`

Comment: @ThomasWard I thought it was a typo because the /etc/resolvconf (or similar) doesn't exist.

Comment: @ThomasWard Please note that the OP said this is WSL.  Systemd / NetPlan should not be in play here, right? WSL normally configures the `/etc/resolv.conf` from the Windows host, unless disabled with the `/etc/wsl.conf` mentioned.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds WSL2 is a fully virtualized environment, so it *could* be involved.  We don't know if they're WSL1.  As OP indicated they had to enable it and then disable it.  If they disable it, nothing's going to manage the DNS, so OP has to handle it themselves.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm not sure that I would call it "fully virtualized".  Even WSL2 uses it's own `init` (PID 1) process to hook the interop between WSL and Windows.  Most importantly for this question, at least, it's that `init` on WSL (both 1 and 2) where the networking is set up.  Really, there's very little "Ubuntu" involved in that side of things, *especially* not Systemd.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Can you elaborate (with an edit to the question) on the "that doesn't work again"?  Does the `resolv.conf` get overwritten, even with the `wsl.conf`?  If so, try removing the spaces around the equals sign (`generateResolvConf=false`).  It's a long shot, but an easy change to try.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds done! but `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` is now deleted when I exit/restart wsl

Comment: Sure, but I thought that's what you wanted?  With it no longer using `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, can you manually create your `/etc/resov.conf` successfully?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I can create it indeed, but when I shut WSL down, the file is deleted.

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comment you said that it was `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` that was being deleted when you restarted.  Was that supposed to be `/etc/resolv.conf`, or is it really both that are deleted?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds In my installation of WSL (I won't speak in general because I don't know), `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. It's the latter that's deleted while the first stays a symlink even when the latter is deleted.

Comment: Bumping, as I am running into the same problem and there is no solution yet

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04, none of solutions seem to work for me - resolv.conf seems to be generated every time after I do wsl --shutdown.

Comment: While Ubuntu WSL still running in a window I ran a `wsl --shutdown` in another CMD window and waited a few seconds. Eventually the WSL session was killed. I then restarted WSL Ubuntu and the `resolv.conf` was still there. Have not yet tested whether it is retained through laptop reboots.

Comment: @NeilG I have two Ubuntu WSL2 instances at my place - 22.04 and 23.04. 22.04 is totally fine after applying suggested workarounds, but 23.04 seems consistent - it loses resolv.conf every single time. No idea why...

Comment: I'm still on 22.04, @GoranMitrovic. I guess I'm happy staying here then. Maybe they "fixed" the bug for WSL on 23.04, and that's why the workarounds no longer work? ;-)

Comment: That's funny @GoranMitrovic, I have just received a SO notification about 1 hour ago, notifying me of your comment from May 9, which I even already replied to! Monkey business! I'm being hunted by revenge voters. Could be them. Unless you have a clue?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420#issuecomment-646479747)

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This seems promising. Unfortunately I recently got rid of Windows so I can't try. If your answer gets sufficiently upvoted, I'll accept it.

Comment: i can confirm this worked for me, thanks !

Comment: Yes it works. The step where it overrides `/etc/wsl.conf` is dangerous though, in case there is something there. The first step is really necessary, removing the symlink.

Comment: In my case I had to reload WSL afterwards, with the `wsl --shutdown` command in PowerShell.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6977) refers to the same thing and emphasises that `/etc/resolv.conf` may start out as a symlink so it needs to be deleted first to create a regular file; there's a bug in WSL so even with `generateResolvConf=false` you need `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` which apparently suppresses that. And note `/etc/wsl.conf` can also have a `[boot]` section line `systemd=true` but I have no advice on what to do about that.

Comment: Confirmed working on my case

Comment: This solution isn't _permanent_ - at least not in my experience. I need to run it every 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to comment on [snuczek's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398053/1604341) but don't have enough reputation.

From the [linked solution](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420#issuecomment-646479747) in their answer, adding:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf=false
```

to `/etc/wsl.conf` does stop wsl from automatically generating the file, but only once it has been shutdown once. Once done, the config will be respected and it's not required to make the `/etc/resolv.conf` file immutable using the `chattr +i` command.

To shutdown wsl, run `wsl --shutdown` in a windows command prompt (this shuts down all WSL distributions).

Of course you'll still need to add your dns servers into the `/etc/resolv.conf` file (for example):

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps will ensure that */etc/resolv.conf* is properly configured with the *nameserver 8.8.8.8* each and every time the wsl starts

1. Adding bashrc entry for initial user

```
echo "sudo su -" >> ~/.bashrc
```

2. Creating sudoers entry for initial user

```
sudo su -
    
echo "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/username
```

3. Adding bashrc entry for root user

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Note:** This will override the contents of the */etc/resolv.conf* file. You can use *sed* command to do any specific modification as required

Comment: there is a problem here. `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink and you will be overwriting the file pointed by the symbolic link. You need to remove the symlink first and only them populate.