# wsl2: resolv.conf stubbornly being regenerated

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, resolv.conf

My /etc/wsl.conf:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

And yet my /etc/resolv.conf continues to regenerate.
I specify:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Only to find it changed to:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.29.128.1
```

Note: I tried the solutions suggested below, none of them helped:

[Why does my resolv.conf file get regenerated every time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30942/why-does-my-resolv-conf-file-get-regenerated-every-time)

Comment: What release Ubuntu are you running in WSL?  resolv.conf is a generated file these days, usually systemd, but it uses 127.0.0.53 for its nameserver, so you must be using something else to manage your network.

Comment: @ubfan1 Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: @Terrance Indeed: ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Dec 19  2022 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

Comment: In this case, @Ya. shows they're using the resolvconf not the newer systemd-resolved. You can follow the top answer's second last paragraph editing `/etc/resolvconf/`, or the last paragraph replacing the symlink with a regular file.

Comment: @DanielT Yep, you are correct. It has been a while since I have even messed with the `resolvconf` but for some reason the `systemd` was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @Daniel T Nope. Tried both prepending name server in dhcp as well as installing resolvconf.

Comment: Also tried replacing the symlink with a regular file.

Comment: @Ya. So what happens with `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` when you replace it with a regular file?

Comment: It stays until I open or close any window to WSL or reload my vscode. Then it gets overwritten to 172... It is not being reset to the sym link.

Comment: Btw. I've updated the question to include the additional lines in resolv.conf. Sorry, I should have done it to begin with. IT reads that 'the file was autonatically generated by WSL"

Comment: I just realized both this question and my answer are a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1347712/1004020 . Except I added the `-f` flag for robustness, and I slightly cleaned up the commands in my answer

Comment: @mchid It does, thx. Looks like that's more or less the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It seems that the immutable file attribute (`chattr +i`) is required.](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420#issuecomment-646479747) Run the following:

```bash
sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chattr -f +i /etc/resolv.conf

# Replace `tee` with `tee -a` if you want to keep wsl.conf modifications
echo $'[network]\ngenerateResolvConf = false' | sudo tee /etc/wsl.conf'
```

Comment: Well I be damned, that seems to be working. Actually I've tried setting it to readonly (which didn't work of course) but didn't know about the immutable attribute. Thanks!